# update and insert action in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Can you tell me what is the wrong? I want to have a stored procedure that can do both update and insert action.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `save_user`(IN `sp_aliasName` VARCHAR(100),IN `sp_password` VARCHAR(100), IN `sp_sex` VARCHAR(100), IN `sp_age` INT(11), IN `sp_userGroup` VARCHAR(100),OUT `sp_number_of_user` INT)    
BEGIN
DECLARE temp INT;
SELECT COUNT(user_id) INTO sp_number_of_user  FROM user WHERE aliasName = sp_aliasname;
temp := sp_number_of_user;
IF temp > 0
THEN
UPDATE user SET aliasName=sp_aliasName,password=sp_password,sex=sp_sex,age=sp_age,userGroup=sp_userGroup 
WHERE aliasName = sp_aliasname ;
ELSE
INSERT INTO user (aliasName,password,sex,age,userGroup)
values (sp_aliasName,sp_password,sp_sex,sp_age,sp_userGroup);
END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your procedure should look like this -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `save_user`(IN `sp_aliasName` VARCHAR(100),IN `sp_password` VARCHAR(100), IN `sp_sex` VARCHAR(100), IN `sp_age` INT(11), IN `sp_userGroup` VARCHAR(100),OUT `sp_number_of_user` INT)    
BEGIN
  DECLARE temp INT;
  SELECT count(user_id) INTO sp_number_of_user FROM user WHERE aliasName = sp_aliasname;
  SET temp := sp_number_of_user;
  IF temp > 0 THEN
    UPDATE user SET aliasName = sp_aliasName, password = sp_password, sex = sp_sex, age = sp_age, userGroup = sp_userGroup
    WHERE aliasName = sp_aliasname;
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO user (aliasName, password, sex, age, userGroup) VALUES (sp_aliasName, sp_password, sp_sex, sp_age, sp_userGroup);
  END IF;
END
```

I added:

- INT type to OUT parameter
- WHERE clause to UPDATE statement (check this condition)

Also, have a look at [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) command, it may do what you need.